# Lollipop: Get top activity name

Tags: android, android-activity, android-task

How to get top activity name in Lollipop?

```
((ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).
   getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
```

is not longer available for Lollipop:

```
     * @deprecated As of {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#LOLLIPOP}, this method
     * is no longer available to third party
     * applications: the introduction of document-centric recents means
     * it can leak person information to the caller.  For backwards compatibility,
     * it will still retu rn a small subset of its data: at least the caller's
     * own tasks, and possibly some other tasks
     * such as home that are known to not be sensitive.
```

Calling from onResume in MyActivity

```
MyApplication.getInstance().saveCurentActivity(MyActivity.this)
saveCurentActivity(Activity a) {
    this.activityName = a.getClass().getSimpleName();
}
```

is no good idea, because MyApplication can be destroyed on error (for example, NPE).

Comment: Please check my answer for a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36660429/4554069

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for me.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)    context.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
String currentTopActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
```

It will give TopActivity.

Comment: getRunningTasks is deprecated

Comment: Use  getAppTasks() and gettaskinfo instead....like below List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = activityManager.getAppTasks();
        ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo taskInfo = tasks.get(0).getTaskInfo();

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long INTERVAL=2000;
                long begin = end - INTERVAL;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                    UsageStatsManager us = (UsageStatsManager) MyServices.this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
                    UsageEvents usageEvents = us.queryEvents(begin, end);
                    while (usageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
                        UsageEvents.Event event = new UsageEvents.Event();
                        usageEvents.getNextEvent(event);
                        if (event.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND) {
                            Log.e("event", "timestamp : " + event.getTimeStamp());
                            Log.e("event", "package name : " + event.getPackageName());
                            Log.e("event", "Class name : " + event.getClassName());
                            //You can find activity name as Class name      

                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: This is API level 22 but not 21.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the original API you are using, but you can track Activity life-cycle changes in *your* app, using an [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) that could be registered via [Application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)). It would get notified whenever an Activity is created, started, resumed, etc. You might be able to track the current Activity using the `onActivityResumed` and `onActivityPaused` hooks.

Comment: good idea, but how I can to store names? Not in MyApplication instance.

Comment: What are you doing the with the names? Could you store in the ActivityLifeCycleCallback and make it a singleton or a static instance?

Comment: I need to save current top activity name into variable for using in my logic. Ill try your solution, thanks.