# Method returns same package name for all Google apps

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, service

I'm working on lock application , In which when user open any app . my app will trigger and if it match with my blocklist then i'm showing lock screen to user.

What I have done so far.

```
public static String getTopAppName(Context context) {
            ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            String strName = "";
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    strName = getLollipopFGAppPackageName(context);
    
    
                } else {
                    strName = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
                }}
        }

private static String getLollipopFGAppPackageName(Context ctx) {

        try {
            UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) ctx.getSystemService("usagestats");
            long milliSecs = 60 * 1000;
            Date date = new Date();
            List<UsageStats> queryUsageStats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, date.getTime() - milliSecs, date.getTime());
            if (queryUsageStats.size() > 0) {
                Log.i("LPU", "queryUsageStats size: " + queryUsageStats.size());
            }
            long recentTime = 0;
            String recentPkg = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < queryUsageStats.size(); i++) {
                UsageStats stats = queryUsageStats.get(i);

                if (i == 0 && !"org.pervacio.pvadiag".equals(stats.getPackageName())) {
                    Log.i("LPU", "PackageName: " + stats.getPackageName() + " " + stats.getLastTimeStamp());
                }
                if (stats.getLastTimeStamp() > recentTime) {
                    recentTime = stats.getLastTimeStamp();
                    recentPkg = stats.getPackageName();
                }
            }
            return recentPkg;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

I'm following [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066580/6880611) to get top running activity in device above Lollipop. I have created background service for that.

**Problem I'm facing :**

**1.** When user block any apps from my application , I'm getting package name of that app . for example (com.google.android.talk, com.google.android.apps.maps, com.android.chrome).

At the time of service  running in background . I'm getting top package name `com.google.android.gsf` for all google apps (maps , hangout ). So it's difficult for me to identify  particular app .

I think the problem is in `getLollipopFGAppPackageName()` but I can't figure out what.

**2.** As mentioned in Some SO posts that  `getLollipopFGAppPackageName()` can only be used at debug time not for actual implementation . So if I wont use this then what might be the correct way to implement this kind of functionality (lock app) in devices above lollipop.

Any help or guidance would be great .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I checked out your code, the array that **queryUsageStats()** method return is not the same order as activities stack, this first item of this list is NOT latest opened app. You have to reorder manually this list by ***getLastTimeUsed***.

Sort by rxJava:

```
 List<UsageStats> queryUsageStats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, currentTime - milliSecs, currentTime);
                rx.Observable.from(queryUsageStats)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .toSortedList((usageStats1, usageStats2) -> compareTo(usageStats2.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats1.getLastTimeUsed()))
                        .subscribe(usageStats -> {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, usageStats.get(0).getPackageName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        });
```

Normal sort:

```
Collections.sort(queryUsageStats, (usageStats1, usageStats2)
                        -> compareTo(usageStats2.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats1.getLastTimeUsed()));

Toast.makeText(ctx, queryUsageStats.get(0).getPackageName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And

```
private int compareTo(long a, long b) {
        return a == b ? 0 : (a > b ? 1 : -1);
    }
```

**And do not forget:**

```
// Declare USAGE_STATS permisssion in manifest

    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

//TODO: Check if user has already enabled Device Administrator, don't start this intent.
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**FURTHER MORE:** An app that can lock other apps is NOT 100% reliable, neither some app-lock with million downloads on Google Play. 

 Generally the target of app-lock is when you want to share your device with other users (your girlfriend, boyfriend, children...) and still keep privacy of some specific apps that you want.

But there are some cases that can break the app-lock:

1. Uninstall the app: even your app is enabled Device Administrator by
   user, they can go Device Administrator, disable your app, uninstall
   it, *or even worse reinstall app-lock, set new password for it. If
   you don't know how to uninstall it again, you will be f_cked :3*.
2. Turn on **Ultra power saving mode** or **Ultra STAMINA mode** (at least on Samsung and Sony devices as I know), in this mode there
   are only some minimum limited apps can show and run(messages, phone
   call...), **ALL app-lock is totally useless in this case**, the
   shared-user can easily read your privacy SMS messages.

*I used to write an app-lock before and these cases broke my dream :), PLEASE mark this answer as accepted if it can resolve your problem.*

 
***I hope you can make a better lock-app feature, reliable enough and good performance. :)***

Comment: thanks for your answer but some of your methods are of RxJava . so if you replace your example with android native . it'd be very helpful

Comment: it's just simple sort desc by getLastTimeUsed :), If you are still need I will update my answer but maybe later, now I'm kind of busy :)

Comment: At your convenience