# Get context of foreground activity in Service

Tags: android, android-activity, service, android-context, google-vr-sdk

I have a service and I want to get context of topmost activity which is currently running on foreground. The service is in my own app and topmost activity is from another app (the activity is not from my app). Is it possible ? If yes, how?

Edit : I need to get context because, I want to apply custom distortion to images rendered by Google VR service. How I plan to do is:

1. Get context of [GvrActivity](https://developers.google.com/vr/reference/android/com/google/vr/sdk/base/GvrActivity) in my service.
2. Get GvrView from the context
3. Access `onDrawFrame()` methods etc. from GvrView and apply custom distortion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066231/how-to-gettopactivity-name-or-get-current-running-application-package-name-in-lo

Comment: I want context and not just package names.

Comment: What do you need it for? You might get more answers if you ask a more specific question. Maybe you wouldn't need the context at all.

Comment: @josephus I have added the reason to get context

Comment: Understood. I'd imagine what you're trying to do is impossible short of having your own flavor of Android.

Imagine the horror when apps have the ability to modify how other apps are drawn (theming is different of course).

Comment: This is not possible. The `Context` of another app is in another OS process. For security reasons your app cannot access memory inside another application's OS process. And thank the Godess for that!

Comment: @DavidWasser thank you! Can you think of any other approach to apply custom distortion? Like apply extra barrel distortion to whatever any VR app is rendering?

Comment: Is it possible to do if phone is rooted?

Answer (score 0):

Service cannot get context of current active activity. But you achieve your scenario other way.

1. Send the local broadcast when the job is finished on service, (`Services` can access `share preference`, `Database`, `broadcast reciever` and etc..).
2. Listen the local broadcast from activity, `onReceive()`, on that function  apply custom distortion to images rendered by google vr service.

Comment: The activity is in another app. I cannot modify that activity.