# get current running application's package name method is not working properly in Android 10

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on app locker to show lock on selected apps by getting top applications's package name. For this purpose I'm calling the method in my service every 1 second to check which application is on top. I have implemented the answers given in these links https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066580/13005440 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/38829083/13005440. Its not working properly in my **pixel 2 (Android 10)** device. The above methods return correct package name for some apps like **youtube** when it opens first time / after minimize but not for other apps like messages, playstore etc. I want to implement my app lock on app minimize.

**Note:** When applications (**messages, playstore** etc) open 1st time it returns correct package name, but when that application goes to background by minimize then re-open app the method will not return its package name.

I have searched a lot but didn't find any way that will work on android 10 properly

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed out in the thread you got your solution from, are you giving the right permissions?

You need this one:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"/>
```

Comment: I added this in the manifest. also I'm giving right permissions "Access usage stats". My method is running well from Kitkat to Pie but not in Android 10

Comment: Then, if it only occurs on android 10 I think some security improvements or the way to handle this has been changed. It will be hard to find a solution because it is realatively new.

Comment: I think there is issue in android 10 at below highlighted lines  queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time)
                currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();

Comment: in these lines Its not picking up the right packageName of top aplication