# how to apply pattern lock on my all apps of my device?

Tags: java, android

i designed a pattern view using this library

'''implementation 'com.andrognito.patternlockview:patternlockview:1.0.0''''

but how to apply pattern lock on all apps on my android device? how to show my pattern app screen when pattern apply on any app in android device? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Long story short: This is not possible. You cannot modify the launch behavior of other applications to go to your custom Activity first, that would be a huge security issue

Comment: @PKlumpp This should be an answer.

Comment: As the pattern lock is using in **Phone Booster** app on play store. To apply pattern lock to all other apps like it. how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already wrote in my comment. what you want to do is not possible. You can modify the behavior of your own application, but not the one of others.

The main reason is security issues. Imagine you have an app that mimics a log-in screen from BankXY, and displays this screen right before your actual BankXY app log-in screen is displayed. This is called phishing, and is one of the most popular attacking scenarios out there. What you would like to implement would not be a security risk, but the tools to make it possible certainly are.

**EDIT:**

This was possible before Android 8.0, where the ability of using `Services` for background executions was significantly limited. It was possible to create a Service that would check the package names of running applications and in case this name is on a black-list, request a pin code for example (See this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440741/how-to-programmatically-set-a-lock-or-pin-for-an-app)). However, you cannot run background Services for an infinite amount of time anymore.

Comment: Please see **phone booster** app on play store. i want to apply pattern lock like it.