# Starting activity, when other app opens

Tags: android

I want to make an App-Locker (When you open any app, you will be prompted to type in a password. If it's correct, the app opens, if not, it doesn't). How can I start an activity when an other app opens?

Comment: It doesn't make sense posting a duplicate question if it does not have an answer

Comment: not possible - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/fNTysSA8mWQ

Comment: Have  you checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623767/how-do-android-app-lock-applications-work

Comment: @RvdK Thanks, I will take a look at that